# Integer parser error when parsing " 0xFF000000"

Tags: java, android, integer

I'm trying to store "0xFF000000" and similar numbers as ints in Java. If I declare a value like this `headerBackgroundColor = 0xFF000000` then everything works fine. But when I parse a json string of `0xFF000000` via either

`Integer.decode(jsonObject.getString("HeaderBackgroundColor"));`
`Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("HeaderBackgroundColor"));`

I get this error - `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "0xFF000000"`

I triple checked that the value is correct in the json and that it is a valid int value. I am at a loss as to why the String won't parse correctly...

Thank you

Comment: I think you using a hex number and parsing it into int ...

Comment: Or rather no, `0x` is not considered in the parsing. You have to remove it, then use the overloaded method. Also, I feel like your number is too big.

Comment: but can 0x ever contain anything useful?

Comment: just doing this -  Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("HeaderTextColor"), 16); also throws the same error

Comment: @David `Ox` is a useful prefix used to indicate hex. But `parseInt` cannot parse it.

Comment: But also, `FF000000` does not fit in an `int`.

Comment: yah i just hit that - java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "FF000000"

Comment: int number = (int)long.parseLong("00000000", 16)

Comment: but it works like this - headerTextColor = 0xFF000000 ? how does that work if it isnt vaild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are parsing colors, try right tool for the task -> `Color` class has method:

```
public static int parseColor(String colorString)
```

and docs say ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String))):

> Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray'.

If you cannot alter how your JSON is build, just replace `0x` with `#` prior parsing.